# rewrite jquery as variable

Tags: jquery, var

I've created a working list switcher here:
http://codepen.io/tincanben/pen/GpjbMQ

It's a bit messy so I'd like to know how I can rewrite the code:

```
$('.switcher a').on('click',function(e) {
if ($(this).hasClass('grid-view')) {
    $('#block-listings ul').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
    $('.switcher a.grid-view').addClass('active-grid');
    $('.switcher a.list-view').removeClass('active-list');
}
else if($(this).hasClass('list-view')) {
    $('#block-listings ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
    $('.switcher a.list-view').addClass('active-list');
    $('.switcher a.grid-view').removeClass('active-grid');
}
});
```

So that it's clean and in the format of:

```
var 
    // General purpose vars
    htmlBody = $('html,body'),
    Window = $(window),
    Document = $(document),
    Switcher = $('#switcher'),

    // Switcher
    switcher = function(){
        var switcher = 
    },

    Ready = function(){
        externalLinks();
        switcher();
    },
```

Comment: You might have better responses here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Something like this?
http://codepen.io/rob-bar/pen/ojBVKB

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Your code isn't defining any variables. I don't see how you could rewrite it so it does nothing by define some variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I recommend you put everything in a self invoking function to protect the code from your global scope, I also prefixed jquery objects with the $ sign, its a good practice (like that you know if the object is already wrapped in jquery or not) and then I took your function and removed the double code with the toggleClass function and a slight different approach on how to check against the active-grid class, happy coding.